# Reverse output ordering in a C struct

Tags: c, struct, output

I am currently working on a project and have a little bit of a road block. I have completed the code required however there is an extra section that requires me to print out the output in the opposite order of what it is at the moment.

For example:

```
21, Fred Nurk
927, Arwen Evensong
```

Should Return:

```
Arwen Evensong (927)
Fred Nurk (21)
```

But is currently returning:

```
Fred Nurk (21)
Arwen Evensong (927)
```

I was wondering if there would be a simple way to do this without changing too much of the code? Sorry if the code is a bit messy and hard to read, there are a few restrictions in place that made this problem quite annoying to write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80
#define MAX_NUM_STUDENTS 500
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 50

typedef struct student_s Student;

struct student_s {
    int age;
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    Student* next;
};

Student studentPool[MAX_NUM_STUDENTS];
int firstFree = 0;


Student* newStudent(const char* name, int age) {
    Student* student = NULL;
    if (firstFree < MAX_NUM_STUDENTS) {
        student = &studentPool[firstFree];
        firstFree += 1;
        strncpy(student->name, name, MAX_NAME_SIZE);
        student->name[MAX_NAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
        student->age = age;
        student->next = NULL;
    }
    return student;
}


Student* readOneStudent(FILE* file)
{
    char *buffer;
    buffer = (char *)malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    Student* student = NULL;
    char* cp = fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file);
    if (cp != NULL) {
        char* commaPos = strchr(buffer, '\040');
        int age = atoi(buffer);
        if (commaPos != NULL && commaPos > buffer) {
            *commaPos = '\0';
            student = newStudent((commaPos+1),age);

        }
    }
    return student;
}

Student* readStudents(FILE *file)
{
    Student* first = NULL;
    Student* last = NULL;
    Student* student = readOneStudent(file);
    while (student != NULL) {
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = last = student;
        }
        else {
            last->next = student;
            last = student;

        }
        student= readOneStudent(file);
    }

    return first;
}


void printOneStudent(Student student)
{

strtok(student.name, "\n");
if (student.name != '\0'){
printf("%s (%d)\n", student.name, student.age);
}
else{
    printf("%s (%d)",student.name, student.age);
}
   }


void printStudents(const Student* student)
{
    while (student != NULL) {
        printOneStudent(*student);
        student = student->next;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    FILE* inputFile = stdin;
    if (inputFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found\n");
    }
    else {
        Student* studentList = readStudents(inputFile);
        printStudents(studentList);
    }
}
```

Comment: make your printStudents a recursive function with trailing output

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you may use recursion to reverse a single-linked list :

```
void printStudentsRev(const Student* student)
{
    if (student != NULL) {
        printStudentsRev(student->next);
        printOneStudent(*student);
    }
}
```

This won't work on very long lists as the stack area is limited

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to construct the list backward here is the code:

```
Student* readStudents(FILE *file)
{
    Student* first = NULL;
    Student* last = NULL;
    Student* student = readOneStudent(file);
    while (student != NULL) {
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = last = student;
            last->next = NULL;
        }
        else {
            student->next = first;
            first = student;
        }
        student = readOneStudent(file);
    }

    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a doubly linked list rather than a singly linked list. Add to your struct.

```
Student* previous
```

Update it accordingly throughout the program. When you go to print, Iterate to the end and print until you are at the front similar to your print students function.

```
void printStudents2(const Student* student){
//iterate to end
    while (student->next != NULL) {
          student=student->next;
    }
    while(student != NULL){
          printOneStudent(*student);
          student = student->previous;
    }
}

Student* readStudents(FILE *file)
{
    Student* first = NULL;
    Student* last = NULL;
    Student* student = readOneStudent(file);
    while (student != NULL) {
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = last = student;
            //add these too
            student ->next = NULL;
            student->previous = NULL;
        }
        else {
            //add this line here
            student->previous = last;
            last->next = student;
            last = student;
            //and this line here
            last->next = NULL;

        }
        student= readOneStudent(file);
    }

    return first;
}
```

Edit: It requires about 10 more lines than the recursive solution but it will work for any length list.